# Workaround for Firefox's lack of support of onUnload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, onbeforeunload, onunload

We have a chat client in our web app. When the user closes the window the chat is in, we provide a chance to cancel in the onBeforeUnload event

```
$(window).on('beforeunload') = function(e) {
  return (e || window.event).returnValue = "Are you sure you'd like to end the chat?";
}
```

Then, if they confirm they would like to end the chat, onUnload is supposed to fire, running a method which does some webapi calls and interacts with our chat server (signalR) to end the chat and alert the other user.

```
$(window).on('unload') = function(e) {
  EndChat();
}
```

As you may know, Firefox does not support onUnload anymore. Any solution I've found for this issue does not take into account wanting to prompt the user before executing the onUnload code. Of course, native js alerts and confirms are not allowed in the onBeforeUnload event.

Comment: You should never rely on anything being done inside the `unload` event, in any browser. If you want to check if the user left, the usual way is to poll.

Comment: `which does some webapi calls and interacts with our chat server (signalR) to end the chat and alert the other user.` - and this works in Chrum/Internet Exploder/Edge/Safari and Opera?

Comment: @JaromandaX It has not been tested in Safari and Opera, but it works in the other three